# Angular directive doesn't work while replacing to ui-select

Tags: angularjs

while using ui-select, I find it's too complicate to write, so I want to simplify it by creating my own directive. But it doesn't work.

```
.directive('crmSelect', function($rootScope) {
 return {
    restrict : 'E',
    replace : true,
    transclude : true,
    scope : true,
    template : '<ui-select> </ui-select>'

   };
})
```

And the html is fairly easy:

```
<crm-select> </crm-select>
```

while running the code, angular report error (Error: [$compile:multidir] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.4/$compile/multidir?p0=crmSelect&p1=%20(mod…3A%20crmui.controllers)&p2=uiSelect&p3=&p4=transclusion&p5=%3Cui-select%3E)

But if I replace the template to be something like template: 'abcde ' , then it works as expected, if I directly use ui-select element in html, it also works correctly.

From the error messages, looks like there is conflict for multiple directives, does anyone knows the root cause and how to fix this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following can be the reasons

- Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.
- Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.
- Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL.

Comment: I tried to set scope to true/false, and set transclution to be true/false, still doesn't work.  I guess it's caused by template,  if ui-select directive define template, then it will conflict with my template definition?  with that being said, I feel it's nearly impossible to achieve my requirement by using custom directive to encapsulate ui-select :(